# How to check if date is today's date with PHP

Tags: php, date

Say, I have 4 dates and the date today is 1/7/16:

```
1/7/16 1:06:02

1/7/16 8:01:24

1/8/16 7:02:23

1/6/16 3:12:34
```

How can I only pick `1/7/16 1:06:02` and `1/7/16 8:01:24`.

What date function from PHP can I use to only get the date of today?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

This is being used as a MYSQL selector.

Example: `$db->query("DELETE * FROM entry WHERE date='$today'");`

How would this work? How can I get my MYSQL query to select only the dates for today?

**UPDATE 2:**
I've tried using `curdate()`, but the code is not working... 
This is what I'm doing:

```
$db->query("DELETE * FROM entry WHERE date=curdate()");
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

**LAST UPDATE:** `curdate()` worked properly...

Comment: Ypu could use date() function.

Comment: `where date=curdate()`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE**: As MySQL query, you can do this as follows:

```
$db->query("DELETE * FROM entry WHERE DATE(date) = CURDATE()");
```

CURDATE() returns today's date.

If you want to do with php, see below to use the DateTime class.

```
$now = new DateTime;
$otherDate = new DateTime('2016-01-01'); // or e.g. 2016-01-01 21:00:02

// Setting the time to 0 will ensure the difference is measured only in days
$now->setTime( 0, 0, 0 );
$otherDate->setTime( 0, 0, 0 );

var_dump($now->diff($otherDate)->days === 0); // Today
var_dump($now->diff($otherDate)->days === -1); // Yesterday
var_dump($now->diff($otherDate)->days === 1); // Tomorrow
```

Comment: the date_format is pointless. it requires a date/datetime as input, so formatting a date into a string, then comparing against ANOTHER date is just a waste of cpucycles. `where date(datefield)=curdate()` would be better, and if the datefield is already a date, then even just a simple `datefield=curdate()` would do.

Comment: Thanks Marc for your cleaner alternative.

Comment: the PHP code will check that the date is in the last 24 hours, not today !

Comment: I tested it 2018-12-11 and I've got a wrong result: `$now = new DateTime;
$otherDate = new DateTime('2018-12-12 01:00:59'); // should be TRUE for 'Tomorrow'

var_dump($now->diff($otherDate)->days === 0); // TRUE, wrong
var_dump($now->diff($otherDate)->days === -1); // FALSE
var_dump($now->diff($otherDate)->days === 1); // FALSE, wrong`

Answer (score 2):

The answer by schellingerht is totally correct, but

```
$now = new DateTime;
```

should be this instead:

```
$now = new DateTime('Today');
```

That will ensure that the date from today with 0 hours and 0 minutes is selected. Otherwise the output could be `Today` even if the date is tomorrow.
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Convert to timestamp and then format for only the date.  Then compare to the same format of todays date:

```
var_dump(
         date('Ymd', strtotime('1/7/16 1:06:02')) === date('Ymd')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using DATE()  (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date.asp). You don't need to convert your dates to a string - this is not efficient.

```
DELETE FROM yourTable WHERE DATE(yourDateField) = DATE(NOW)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could compare today's date with `Y-m-d` format, with your date parsed with the same format.

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$otherdate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('2022-02-02 16:00:26'));

if($today === $otherdate){
   \\ your code for Today
} else {
   \\ your code for not Today
}
```